# document ready runs in a loop (after adding query string)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, document-ready

I have a action method that returns a view and pass a view model to the view,
after calling this method in another section of my application with passing input parameter
url will be look like this (localhost:51999:\Home\Onlineplayer{guid})

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnlinePlayer(Guid id)
    {
        if (id != Guid.Empty)
        {
            var requestedFeed = await _feedService.FindOneAsync(id);
            var feedOwnerName = requestedFeed.OwnerName;
            
            ISpecification<Feed> spec = new FeedWithNotEndedStateSpec()
                .And(new FeedWithVerifiedStateSpec())
                .And(new FeedWithSpecificOwnerNameSpec(feedOwnerName));

            onlinePlayerVm.LatestMusics = await _feedService.GetListBySpecAsync<FeedPlayerDTOVm>
                    (new PaginationFilter(), spec);

            return View(onlinePlayerVm);
        }
        onlinePlayerVm.LatestMusics = 
            await _feedService.GetListAsync<FeedPlayerDTOVm>(new PaginationFilter(1, 20));
            
        return View(onlinePlayerVm);
    }
```

The OnlinePlayer.cshtml has a 'document.Ready()' jquery function to calls some functions in page loading:

```
<script src="~/js/Custom/AudioPlayer.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        _latestMusicCurrentPage = 1;
        _topMusicCurrentPage = 1;
        _popMusicCurrentPage = 1;

        //GrabLatestMusics();

        if (@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString().ToLower()) {
            SaveLocalPlaylistToDatabaseAfterLogin();
            //GrabUserPlaylists();
        }
        //LoadLocalPlaylists();

        var item = $("#playlistContainer").find("p[data-id=1]");
        PlayThisFromList(this, item, false);


        $(".RemoveFromList").click(function (e) {
            var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $(this).closest("p[data-id='" + dataId + "']").remove();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(".DownloadThisMusic").click(function (e) {
            var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
            PNotifyToasterWithParam("error", "پیاده سازی نشده است")
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

    });
    function GrabLatestMusics() {
        debugger
        $.post('LatestMusic', { pageIndex: _topMusicCurrentPage }, function (data) {
            $("#latestSongsContainer").append(data);
        }).done(function () {
            SetColumntResizingAfterPlayerHidden();
        });;
    }
</script>
```

**Problem**
The page and it's scripts works fine when the **GrabLatestMusics()** function is comment, but after uncommenting this function and passing and Id in url query string, the page will crash and document ready execute over and over and sends infinite requests to **OnlinePlayer(Guid id)** action method in controller. how can I solve this problem!?

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"the page will crash"*?  Is the problem on the server side or the client side?  Is an exception thrown?  If so, what type, what message, and what does the stack look like?  Is it something else?

Comment: @Flydog57  No exception witll throw, the error is on client side
After I uncomment that "GrabLatestMusic" this method calls over and over in document ready and some scripts not works anymore

Comment: What is the returned `data` of the POST request that you made to `LatestMusic`? And can you share the code of function `SetColumntResizingAfterPlayerHidden`?

Comment: @FeiHan ,  the returned data is a list in both cases , one of them with 20 rows and another with one related to input Id.
~function SetColumntResizingAfterPlayerHidden() {
    var $playlistCol = $("#playlistColumn");
    var _playlistColumntFullScreenFlag = $playlistCol.attr('isFullScreen');
    if (_playlistColumntFullScreenFlag == "true") {
        $playlistCol.find('div.col-md-3').removeClass('col-md-3').addClass('col-md-2');
    }
    else {
        $playlistCol.find('div.col-md-2').removeClass('col-md-2').addClass('col-md-3');
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GrabLatestMusics method you should use full address with Controller and Action. (also Area if you need)

```
function GrabLatestMusics() {
        $.post('/YourArea/YourController/LatestMusic', ...
```